# Chef replace _line error

Tags: automation, chef-infra, openstack

I have created recipe for sshd_config changes

```
ruby_block "replace_line" do
  block do
    file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("/home/rd250y/sshd_config")
    file.search_file_replace_line("HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key", "#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key")
    file.search_file_replace_line("HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key", "#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key")
    file.search_file_replace_line('PermitRootLogin *', 'PermitRootLogin no')
    file.search_file_replace_line('PasswordAuthentication *', 'PasswordAuthentication no')
    file.search_file_replace_line('ChallengeResponseAuthentication *', 'ChallengeResponseAuthentication no')
    file.write_file
  end
end
```

When i run this recipe on node, Its replace entire occurrence. I want to change only first occurrence of search

```
cat sshd_config | grep Permit
PermitRootLogin no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
PermitRootLogin no
```

Kindly help me on this

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a template
https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `FileEdit`. It is an internal class and not supported for external use. Unfortunately we didn't communicate this clearly for many years and it ended up in a lot of blog posts and even some documentation. Sorry. We recommend managing the whole file as a `template` or `cookbook_file` as this is much more convergent and delta updates often lead to brittle recipes, but if you must, then look at existing custom resources like the `poise-file` and `line` cookbooks.